# Aggregate timeseries data over various timeframes

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a question about how to aggregate time series data that is coming into DynamoDB.

Currently energy usage data is coming into DynamoDB every 30 seconds per device. The devices are also spread across many timezones.

I want to show the aggregate energy usage over one hour, one day, one month, and one year.

I know one way that I can do it is run a Lambda on a 1 hour cron job that takes all of the readings for the previous hour and adds them all together and then records that in a different table in.

At the same time in that cron job the Lambda can check if any devices timezones just had their day end, and if so batch up the previous 24 hours for into a single day reading.

The same goes for month, and year.

But something tells me there is a another, better, way to do all this (probably using some otherAWS service which I am not thinking of)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a cron job, you can use dynamoDB streams.

In this case, when a record comes into your data collection table, it can kick off a lambda function that updates your aggregate tables. That will allow you to get more timely updates into the aggregate tables. The logic for what hour/day/month/year your record gets aggregated should be in that lambda.

Also, I’d use a cloud watch event instead of cron...